# Yielding even numbers in a reverse iterator

Tags: rust, iterator

I wish to create an iterator which yields even numbers from a value in reverse order.

This program demonstrates the issue. It reads two integers from command line and prints
even numbers between them in decreasing order. It is sufficient to expect min value to be even.

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
fn main() {
    // Read numbers
    let mut input = io::BufReader::new(io::stdin());
    let mut buf = String::new();
    input.read_line(&mut buf).unwrap();

    let mut split = buf.split(" ");
    let min = split.next().unwrap().trim().parse::<i64>().unwrap();
    let max = split.next().unwrap().trim().parse::<i64>().unwrap();
    // Attempt to generate the iterator
    let payload: String = (min..max)
        .rev()
        .step_by(2)
        .map(|x| x.to_string() + " ")
        .collect();
    println!("{payload}");
}
```

However, for example input of `2 6`, program yields `5 3` when I would expect the numbers to be `4 2`.

What is the way to create an iterator which would here produce `4 2` as  unreversed version does yield `2 4`?

Comment: You could adjust the maximum to be even (`max &= !1`) and use `min..=max` as the range.

Comment: What does that `&= !1` even do? Evil little bit hack.

Comment: But yeah, please put up as an answer if you think that would be optimal way to achieve this.

Comment: This masks the lowest bit and sets it to zero.

Comment: or move `.rev()` to after `.step_by(2)`

Comment: @valllentin that will cause compiler error.

Comment: You specify "from any  maximum". If you want the code to work from any minimum, you also need to adjust the minimum to the next even number using `min += min & 1`.

Comment: What is the "correct iterator" you want? One that outputs `4 2` or one that outputs `6 4 2`? You need to account for the fact that `x.rev()` is not simply a matter of swapping the endpoints and counting the other way.

Comment: That is, with `x` you always include `x.start` but never include `x.end`. With `x.rev()`, you *might* include `x.end`, and only include `x.start` when you include `x.end`.

Comment: @chepner I have made the question more clear in that aspect.

Comment: @vahvero [swapping `rev` and `step_by` will not result in a compiler error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=950da268c33eb588f2a87422b796e350) you must have messed up somewhere else.

Comment: `step_by(2)` is a hack that only selects even numbers when the even numbers are at even positions in the first place. That's true for `(even..odd)` ranges, but not ranges in general, and `rev()` doesn't preserve the even-numbers-at-even-positions property. The simplest thing to do would be to use `filter` to select even values directly, regardless of where they are. (1/2)

Comment: I'm assuming you are looking for something more efficient, that doesn't involve applying a predicate to every value, but takes advantage of the fact that regardless of whether the iterator starts with an even or odd number, even and odd numbers alternate. For that, you need to adjust the logic depending on whether the first number is even or odd. (2/2)

Comment: @vahvero you are getting downvotes because the question is based on a flawed premise; the iterator and `rev` work as specified. A range `(min..max)` is evaluated as [min,max) and is evaluated before `rev` is called. It is your expectation that your  code is correct that is unrealistic.

Comment: @cafce25 it does error out if the value of maximum is not known during compilation. I have tried to keep the question as simple as possible, but it should error with "error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::ops::Range<i64>: ExactSizeIterator` is not satisfied" if end point is dynamic.

Comment: @vahvero it appears your question does not include a [mre] then.

Comment: @cafce25 I have now altered the code included in the question to better demonstrate the question.

Comment: Flipping `rev` and `step_by` still works, if you don't use `i64` as your type, but for example `i32` or `isize`.

Comment: @cafce25 Yes, can confirm. I'd consider that superior to accepted answer, no extra calls. I wasn't even aware that type change could affect ranging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`step_by(2)` works under the assumption of an iterator that strictly alternates even and odd numbers, but also *starts* with an even number. That's true for a `Range` that starts with an even number, but not true for the reversal of every `Range`. In particular, the first element of `(2..6).rev()` is odd.

To accommodate reversed ranges that might start with odd numbers, use `skip_while`:

```
let a = (2..6).rev()
        .skip_while(|x| x % 2 == 1)
        .step_by(2)
        .map(|x| x.to_string() + " ")
        .collect();
println!("{a}");
```

`(2..6).rev()` starts with `5`, but `(2..6).rev().skips_while(...)` starts with `4`. Note that `(2..5).rev()` and `(2..5).rev().skips_while(...)` would be equivalent, as nothing from the original iterator is skipped.

Regarding efficiency, the predicate will be applied to at most 2 elements in order to satisfy the precondition required for `step_by(2)`, compared to

```
let a = (2..6).rev()
        .filter(|x| x % 2 == 0)
        .map(|x| x.to_string() + " ")
        .collect();
```

which can't use any information about the structure of `(2..6).rev()` to apply the given predicate fewer than O(n) times.